# Prove Inequality $p^n+q^n+r^n \geq p^m+q^m+r^m$ when $pqr=1, n > m \geq 0$

Tags: inequality

> Prove Inequality $$p^n+q^n+r^n \geq p^m+q^m+r^m$$ when $pqr=1, n > m \geq 0, p,q,r >0$

Help me to prove this thm... I think it use AM-GM, But It work not useful to me...

Comment: Is this supposed to be correct for $p=-100$, $q=-\frac1{10}$, $r=\frac1{10}$, $n=3$, $m=1$?

Comment: @user745082 I solved your problem for positive variables. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch thant... I'll fix right now

Comment: @user745082 Show please, how exactly you tried to use AM-GM?

Comment: In this site, you need to show what effort you have put in to solve the problem, else you will get downvotes and not complete answers.  I have given a hint, though you need to add your own attempt also in the question if you want anything more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** With $\alpha = \frac13\left(1-\frac{m}n\right)$ weighted AM-GM gives $(1-2\alpha) p^n +\alpha q^n + \alpha r^n \geqslant p^{n(1-2\alpha)}\cdot q^{n\alpha}\cdot r^{n \alpha} = p^m \cdot(pqr)^{n\alpha}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $p= e^x, q = e^y$ and $r = e^z$ then $x + y + z =0$. Consider the function $f(t) =e^{tx} + e^{ty} + e^{tz}, t\geq 0$. We have
$$f'(t) = x e^{tx} + y e^{ty} + z e^{tz},\quad f'(0) = x + y  + z  =0,$$
and
$$f''(t) = x^2 e^{tx} + y^2 e^{ty} + z^2 e^{tz} \geq 0.$$
Hence $f'(t) \geq f'(0) =0$ for $t\geq 0$. Consequently, $t \to f(t)$ is non-decreasing function on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score -1):

$RHS=(p^m+q^m+r^m)(pqr)^\frac{n-m}{3}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{sym} p^\frac{n+2m}{3}q^\frac{n-m}{3}r^\frac{n-m}{3} \\ LHS=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{sym} p^nq^0r^0 \\ \because (n,0,0)\succ(\frac{n+2m}{3},\frac{n-m}{3},\frac{n-m}{3}) \\ \therefore LHS \ge RHS$

By [Muirhead's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality).